# signalR client disconnection

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I am making a chat application using signalR and am wondering if I can capture disconnection on client side and then call a method on the hub?

For example I want to do something like this:

```
var myHub = $.connection.myHub;
$.connection.hub.start();

myHub.disconnect(function () { myHub.server.someMethod(username) });
```

where myHub.disconnect is the event when a user disconnects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot.  When disconnect triggers the connection will already be in the disconnected state which does not allow any more methods to be triggered.

If you want to perform logic after a connection has disconnected tie into the OnDisconnected override on hub.  For instance:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        // Do what you want here
        return base.OnDisconnected();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, hmm is there anyway I can pass in an argument to OnDisconneced? Or is that cannot be done because the client has already disconnected?

Comment: You can't pass an argument to OnDisconnected and any data you attempt to send to the disconnected client will not reach the client.  Once OnDisconnected fires the client is dead.